# count characters in a word in text file python and write those characters into a csv file

Tags: string, python-2.7

i have a text file test.txt with words as apple,ant,dog,cat,son etc. I want python to calculate the total number of characters for all words in text file

```
Eg:
Word Letters
Ant   3
Apple 5
Dog   3
Cat   3
Son   3
```

This is what I have tried:

```
string = open('file.txt').read()

for word in string.split():
    print len(word)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of any attempts you have already tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Counting Words In A Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778341/python-counting-words-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Not a duplicate of above question as it prints the number of each letter whereas I'm looking for each word in text file, which I couldn't get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have on word per line you can use this :

```
def main():
string = open('Newfile.txt').read()
for word in string.split():
    print ("{} {}".format(word, len(word)))
main()
```

[Try it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdnMxYXNQcFlCamM)

Comment: I'm looking for a shorter and efficient code to read all words in text file and print the number of characters in each word

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: Can you explain me how to write those strings into a csv file??

Comment: Please post it as a new question as it is another topic and also to avoid long discussions on comment :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141983/discussion-between-anonymous-and-reda-maachi).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Reda Maachi's answer, if you have the same word occurring multiple times in the text document, you can convert the split string to a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Iv also included a line that converts all words to lowercase in the event that you have mixed cases.

```
string = string.split()
string = [x.lower() for x in string]
string = set(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

```
from collections import Counter
file=open('file.txt','r')
words = Counter(file.read().split())
for item in words.items():
    print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
```